# How do you kill the dragon in Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep when it keeps regenerating health?

Tags: borderlands-2, borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault

This DLC is the worst in terms of gameplay balance.  I really like the concept behind Tiny Tina role playing a game with the vault hunters, however I am annoyed that the DLC is so frustratingly hard at times. I'm level 52 Zer0 playing solo in TVHM and am trying to enter the Dragon Keep where you have to battle the Handsome Dragon (also level 52) on a bridge with Roland.  Whenever we get its health down to about 25% remaining, it flies away out of sight and regenerates its health.

How are you supposed to kill this thing?

Comment: I don't know this particular game, but as an experienced dragon killer I have to ask - why do you allow it to fly away? The standard generic tricks are: 1) nets, boulders and spells to pin it to the ground 2) poisons and spells that blocks regeneration 3) poisons that works faster than regeneration 4) flying yourself 5) long distance siege arrows to hit it in flight. In order of effectiveness. Are all of these impossible in your game?

Comment: @Mołot, do you have any idea of what game the question is about? Like, you know, the genre? :-)

Comment: Just as an aside, it's supposed to be horribly balanced.  Tina is an inexperienced DM, and as such might throw the players challenges that are too easy or too hard.  You should also probably be a little higher level.

Comment: @MBraedley It is, lore-wise, but aside from Dukes of Ork, I do not recall anything that exceptionally hard. Tina's lack of experience takes form as explicitly Ultra Mega Badass Treants and stuff :-) On the subject of dragons, though, I frankly do not remember that particular one flying away at all :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I successfully killed the level 52 Handsome Dragon!  It took a while, and I did die once, and I'm glad that's over!

I'm answering my own question because comments are too restrictive in length and formatting for my response.

Thanks Keith for your suggestions, the key takeaway I got from you was to keep constant pressure on the dragon, and because of that, I realized that the dragon wasn't actually flying out of the area, just *very high* so I was losing visibility of it from where I was taking cover at the end of the bridge near the entry gate.  Once I began tracking it to keep some sort of damage going, I saw what it was doing and was able to use the SMG and assault rifle to keep firing while it was soaring to the top of the building - where I assume it would regenerate health if I hadn't kept the damage going.

Some other things I learned:

1. On my playthrough, which is the first time through the DLC, I
   couldn't simply run across the bridge to enter Dragon's Keep, I had
   to defeat the dragon to continue the quest.
2. There are two ammo shrines and several ammo crates near the center
   of the bridge, which I hadn't initially noticed while maintaining
   cover at the entry gate end of the bridge.  When the dragon loops
   under the bridge or soars to the top of the building, take the
   opportunity to rush out and restock.  A good shield and
   health-regeneration class mod help in case it bombards you with fire
   while you're out of cover.
3. After you confront the dragon, you'll initially be on your own. 
   Eventually Tiny Tina will summon Roland to help out in the fight. 
   In my case, Roland never threw down a turret, but you can watch him
   to help determine the dragon's position.
4. The dragon has a pattern of attack where it sometimes hovers over
   the bridge.  A launcher comes in handy then, as well as near the end
   of the fight to help knock down those last health points, slag it
   and switch weapons when you see an opportunity to use the launcher.

Comment: Good answer. I think I remember my turret shooting at the dragon the whole time, which accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a level 41 Siren and it wasn't that hard to defeat the Handsome Dragon. Rolans does most of the work with the dragon, just shoot at it when you have the chance. Focus mainly on the baby dragons and if your shield or health is low, crouch and walk under the 3/4 lowered gate and let yourself heal before you go back out to fight.

Answer (score 0):

- Focus on high DPS guns and elemental effects that continue to cause damage over time, or team with someone how does.
- Failing that maximise the amount of damage you can do in a small window so that not all its health returns.
- Keep it slagged.
- If those fail, play with someone who can help keep the damage constant.
- Finally, you can just let it across the bridge without killing the dragon, but you won't get the XP and loot.

Comment: How can you enter the Keep exactly without killing the dragon? Is there a timer or something? The Sorcerer is supposed to open the door only *after* the dragon is slain, isn't he?

Comment: @Keith I'm using a level 48 slag Impetuous Gospel SMG with 3.2k damage and 9.0 fire rate, a level 50 corrosive 4 ammo per shot Twin Dart pistol with 10.4k x 2 damage, and a level 50 explosive Rigorous Lance assault rifle with 10.9k damage -- all purple, as my weapons.  So the trick is to keep constant damage so it doesn't fly away?